# SQL: search of nearest in 2d square and circle

Tags: php, sql, search, 2d

I have a table: points

it has 2 filds: X, Y

each row represents a dot on 2d field

I want to be capable of performing search of dots with in some radius R like

[image]

and is square with side A like

[image]

BTW: I use PHP to access my DB.

My main point is to get nearest to center of figure point as first result in the quqe like
[image]

How to do such thing in SQL?

Comment: I am a bit confused. In the first 2 pictures, the red dot appears to be the center of the square and the circle, but not in the 3rd picture. Why is that?

Comment: +1 for diagrams, though things don't really match the text :) see last diagram - the red dot is not the closest to center(!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematically point in circle statisfies equation

```
(c.X-p.X)^2 + (c.Y-p.Y)^2 <= R^2
```

Where **c** is the cetner of circle, **p** - point, **R** - radius

For square

```
max(abs(c.X-p.X),abs(c.Y-p.Y)) <= A/2
```

Where **c** is the cetner of square, **p** - point, **A** - side of square

You can just write theese equations in any language.

Left side of equations called *distance* for various *measures*. For finding nearest point you should order resultset by *distance* asceniding and take first result.

Something like this:

```
select top 1 p.X, p.X from Points p
otrder by ((@x - p.X)*(@x - p.X)+(@y - p.Y)*(@y - p.Y))
```

Comment: Well, the first expression is ok, the second one not so much (it should be `max(...) <= A/2`). Also, equation is 'a mathematical statement that asserts the equality of two expressions'.

Answer (score 2):

Gandjustas answer is an ok solution if the your queries are not the core of your application. If this geometircal/spatial data is very important to you and you need speed when working with such data specifically you should look into geospatial extensions for your RDBMS.

I will assume that you use mysql, you have [spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) on your disposal.
With proper data types and indexes that will give you

[Distance(g1, g2)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions-that-test-spatial-relationships-between-geometries.html#function_distance)

and other usefull functions.